# Flutter cached_network_image cause app to crash

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

My app uses a-lot of cached images which (I think is the reason causing my app to crash) when i scroll to view so many at one time.

My app is all about images inside list/grid view.

Is it good practice to cache them all?

**Note:
Please note I'm using SliverGrid which is loading images lazily.**

Comment: well, yes but you should care about the sizes of the images that you receive from your backend, avoid receiving bigger images

Comment: If you are running into memory issues, and that's the cause of your crash, make sure that you are using `ListView.builder`, its much more memory efficient than a `ListView(children: [...])`, when dealing with large lists. 

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html

Comment: Im actually using SliverGrid with delegate of Child builder. But unfortunately this is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

If you going to manage a buch of amount image is better, download them to a local directory and take the url like a name in a Data Base then you can ask on every request if your url is on your data base if is there then the file in your directory exist if not, you do the request and store it  file in directory and name on db. This is better when your app manage a buch of information in cache like image, because on some devices the app can be crash o even restar the device.